# "Патронаж" и "патронат"

Tags: недопустимая-метка, лексика

В чем разница между двумя этими словами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изначально разницы не было, но сейчас слово "патронаж" употребляется только в медицинской терминологии и обозначает патронажных медсестер, которые приходят на дом к больному.
Патронат же - это курирование государством или лично президентом какого-либо мероприятния.
Например: "Храм строится под патронатом президента Украины".

Answer (score 1):

Патронаж (от франц. patronage – покровительство, попечительство) – 1) 
книжное, устарелое: то же, что патронат; покровительство: Боясь сначала смиренной 
роли наших соотечественников и патронажа великих людей… (Герцен); 2) 
система медицинского обслуживания больных и детей раннего возраста в 
домашних условиях: патронаж беременных и детей; патронаж психических 
больных.
Патронат (позднелат. patronatus, от лат. patronus – покровитель) – 1) особая 
форма покровительства в Древнем Риме; 2) вообще покровительство со стороны 
кого-нибудь; 3) в СССР: воспитание детей-сирот и детей, потерявших связь с 
родителями, в семьях трудящихся под контролем государственных 
организаций. 
Третье значение слова патронат (под номером 2) зафиксировано и в МАС, в 
«Словаре русского языка» С. И. Ожегова (1989). В словаре Ожегова слово 
патронаж зафиксировано только в одном значении – «регулярное оказание 
лечебно-профилактической помощи на дому новорожденным и некоторым 
категориям 
больных».
В 90-ые годы прошлого столетия под влиянием социальных факторов 
происходит актуализация книжного устарелого значения слова патронаж (= покровительство). В «Толковом словаре русского языка» С. И. Ожегова и Н. Ю. 
Шведовой (М., 1997) зафиксированы как устойчивые выражения под патронажем 
кого - то же, что под патронатом, под патронатом кого – под 
постоянным наблюдением, содействием и 
руководством.
Таким образом, слово патронаж действительно в одном из значений 
связано с медициной. Однако выражения под патронажем и под 
патронатом употребляются равноправно, они синонимичны, их значение – 
«под наблюдением, содействием и руководством кого-либо, чего-либо».